# Object Pooling with Generics

Tags: c#, generics, object-pooling

I am trying to create a manager for object pools such that I can call a method from my manager in order to retrieve a reserved object in the pool or to create a new object when necessary. The objects to be pooled can vary greatly but must all inherit from a `PooledObject` class. There should never be any direct instance of the `PooledObject` class, only classes that extend `PooledObject` should be instantiated.

The problem is with the second portion, where I need to create a new object. I cannot instantiate a PooledObject as it is abstract, but including a `new()` constraint to the `T` generic does not allow `Manager` to instantiate the dictionary that manages the different `PooledObjects`. Below is a snippet of my code.

```
public class Manager{
    private Dictionary<Type, Pool<PooledObject>> _objects;

    public Manager()
    {
        _objects = new Dictionary<Type, Pool<PooledObject>>();
    }
    ...
}

public class Pool<T> where T : PooledObject{
    ...
    public T newObject(){
        ...
        var newT = new T(); // Error on this line
        ...
    }
    ...
}

public abstract class PooledObject{
    ...
}
```

How do I make it so that my generic `T` derives from a class that extends `PooledObject` and is not abstract so I can use the default constructor?

Comment: I tried that but my ```Manager``` will throw this error instead: 'PooledObject' must be a non-abstract type with a public parameterless constructor in order to use it as parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'Pool<T>'

Comment: You'll probably need to use [`Activator.CreateInstance`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.activator.createinstance?view=netcore-3.1) to instantiate a new object.

Comment: Try this `var newT = Activator.CreateInstance<T>();`

Comment: There are lots of possible ways to address this, but the most common I've seen are reflection (`Activator.CreateInstance()`) or inversion of control (i.e. passing a factory method delegate to the pooling object). See duplicates for examples of those and other alternatives.

Comment: @PeterDuniho Thank you, I think I will try the inversion of control method. As I understand, there is significant time cost to using reflection, and I am not sure if it would erase the benefits I get from using a pool in the first place.

Comment: Yes, I would use the factory delegate myself. That said, in some scenarios you need reflection (i.e. when for whatever reason it's impractical or impossible to require the caller to provide the factory delegate); in those cases, you can address the time cost issue by using reflection to build an `Expression`, and then compiling that into a delegate which is then itself cached. You incur the overhead only once, after that it's as fast as IoC.